# android save text drawed bitmap to jpeg file

Tags: android, bitmap, save, jpeg

I try to make an android app 
and it must contain bitmap to jpeg file method

Here is what i have to do

1.create BitmapDrawable object

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)res.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_pic);
```

2.create Bitmap object

```
    Bitmap bit = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
```

3.create set Bitmap on canvas object

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(bit,0,0,null)
```

4.drawText "helloworld" on canvas

```
    Paint pnt = new Paint();
    pnt.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawText("helloworld",100,100,pnt);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.restore();
```

and this code is what I tried to do to save Bitmap(or canvas) to Jepg File

a.

```
    bit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JEPG, 100 , fileOutputStream);
```

but this can save original image(without text)
so, I used code b.

b.

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Drawable drawable =getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_pic);
    view.layout(0,0,drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    view.bulidDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap save_bit = view.getDrawingCache();  

    save_bit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

and this cause nullpoint exception, and logcat send me a message 'View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 31325840 bytes, only 3686400 available'

what do I do to save text drawed bitmap to file 
please give me your opinion

Comment: What's the size of your image and what's the actual output form logcat?

Comment: have you tried calling `getDrawingCache(true)` inside your code 'b'?

Comment: @blipinsk yes, i tried it but result was same.

Comment: @  pablisco size of image is A4, actual output width : 2317 , height:3380